# Litmust test for existence of a function from irregular shape to a square

Tags: general-topology

Let's suppose I have an simple irregular shape A in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ and I am hoping to map this irregular shape A in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to a square B in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Is there a litmus test or a theorem which would allow me to determine if such a function exists?

Comment: Yes A is uncountable.

Comment: @WilliamElliot this only works if $\aleph_1=2^{\aleph_0}$. Mathematicing, what would you want to assume about your map: into, onto (you ought to mean onto), continuous? If you assume continuous, what do you mean by a square, is it only the edges, or do you also include the interior of the square?

Comment: For |A| = c, any of those squares will suffice.

Comment: Edited: "A in $R^{2}$"